# How to optimize type descriptions in this calculator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm a new person in `TypeScript`, tell me how to optimize the data types in this code what i would not write all time `number`. I read that it can be done, through `generics` tell me how to properly and briefly describe this code

```js
interface ICalculator {
    add(num: number): number;
    subtract(num: number): number;
    multiply(num: number): number;
    divide(num: number): number;
    print(): void;
}

class Calculator implements ICalculator {
    protected _res: number;

    add(num:number) {
        return this._res = num + num;
    }

    subtract(num:number) {
        return this._res = num - num;
    }

    multiply(num:number) {
        return this._res = num * num;
    }

    divide(num:number) {
        return this._res = num / num;
    }

    print():void {
        console.log(`Currently value: ${this._res}`);
    }
}
let calc1 = new Calculator();
calc1.add(1);calc1.add(1);
calc1.print();
```

Comment: Just remove the interface? Why do you need it, it’s not Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already wrote out the type definitions for every function in the interface you can skip re-adding types to them when you are defining them.

This would be type-wise identical:

```
interface ICalculator {
    add(num: number): number;
    subtract(num: number): number;
    multiply(num: number): number;
    divide(num: number): number;
    print(): void;
}

class Calculator implements ICalculator {
    protected _res: number;

    add(num) {
        return this._res = num + num;
    }

    subtract(num) {
        return this._res = num - num;
    }

    multiply(num) {
        return this._res = num * num;
    }

    divide(num) {
        return this._res = num / num;
    }

    print() {
        console.log(`Currently value: ${this._res}`);
    }
}
```

you can also define the Type of function for a bit more refactoring:

```
type NumberOperation = (num: number) => number

interface ICalculator {
    add: NumberOperation
    subtract: NumberOperation
    multiply: NumberOperation
    divide: NumberOperation
    print(): void;
}
```

---

Edit:
 Titian Cernicova-Dragomir is correct `Class method parameter are never inferred, they will be implicitly typed to any`

If you do not want to type each function inside the class you can use the interface when declaring a class instance:

```
const calc: ICalculator = new Calculator()

calc.add('string') // type error
```

Comment: Your version of `Calculator` is NOT identical. Class method parameter are never inferred, they will be implicitly typed to any unless you have `noImplicityAny` in which case you would get an error!!